# Using MAX for date but adding column to group on 'breaks' the query - sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I Have a table which holds date but I need to know the latest date where a condition is true per location, only issue is once I add a column called 'notes' it breaks the query and returns too many rows, current query is ...

```
SELECT
        Location,
        MAX(date) AS date,
        type,
        notes
  FROM NotesTable a
 INNER JOIN Location b on a.LocationID = b.LocationID
 INNER JOIN Type c on a.typeid = c.typeid
 WHERE typeid <> 8
 GROUP BY Location, type, notes
```

If I comment out the notes column then it works fine but as soon as I add that to the grouping it then returns more rows than required.

Have tried using a subquery but still cant get it working, subquery below

```
SELECT
        r.location,
        r.date,
        r.type,
        t.notes
  FROM (SELECT Location, MAX(date), type
          FROM NotesTable a INNER JOIN Location b on a.LocationID = b.LocationID
         INNER JOIN Type c on a.typeid = c.typeid
         WHERE typeid <> 8
         GROUP BY location,type
        ) r
INNER JOIN NotesTable t ON t.date = r.date
```

Anyone got any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from
(
     SELECT Location,Date, Type, Notes, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Location, Type order by date desc) RN 
     FROM
          NotesTable a
           INNER JOIN Location b on a.LocationID = b.LocationID
           INNER JOIN Type c on a.typeid = c.typeid
      WHERE typeid <> 8
) v
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried this one and it still returns duplicates, one location has 8 rows for example when there should only be 1

Comment: returns more rows than it should unfortunately

Comment: Perhaps some sample data and expected results would help clarify

Comment: @user1505127 If you remove `notes` from `partition by ... notes` this answer should be correct.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, yeah that sorted it out, cheers for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct, you need to add this additional condition in `ON` clause

```
    AND
    t.location = r.location AND
    t.type = r.type
```

full query,

```
SELECT r.location
     , r.DATE
     , r.type
     , t.notes
FROM (
    SELECT Location
         , MAX(DATE) maxDate
         , type
    FROM NotesTable a
        INNER JOIN Location b
            ON a.LocationID = b.LocationID
        INNER JOIN Type c
            ON a.typeid = c.typeid
    WHERE typeid <> 8
    GROUP BY location
            , type
    ) r
INNER JOIN NotesTable t
    ON t.DATE = r.maxDate AND
        t.location = r.location AND
        t.type = r.type
```

Comment: I get invalid column name 'location' and invalid column name 'type', due to these tables not existing in the NotesTable? Do I need to add 2 other INNER JOINS onto the Location and Type tables?

Comment: Tried Inner joing to join on location and type - INNER JOIN Location l ON l.Location = r.Location INNER JOIN type e ON e.type= r.type but that returned duplicate locations :(